# Как сохранить в массив данные после SELECT *

Tags: php, mysql

Друзья, помогите разобраться.

У меня есть запрос:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM multiplys WHERE sale = '$data_sale[id]'");
$multiply = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Я бы хотел пропарсить в другом цикле массив $multiply в таком виде:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++)
{
  echo $multiply['0']['title'];
}
```

Сразу замечу, что парсить нужно именно в моем цикле, так как он обрабатывает другие данные, прошу не предлагать while($multiply = mysql_fetch_array(result)), так как мне нужен конкретный вариант, что я описал.

В общем я хочу получить двумерный массив после выполнения запроса к бд и пропарсить его в таком виде:

```
$multiply['0']['title'];
```

Comment: ну так возьмите `mysql_num_rows` и пробегайте циклом от 0 до `mysql_num_rows` и там уже делайте `fetch(result)`...кто ж вам не дает?

Comment: Ну как вариант да, то что вы предлагаете подойдет. А есть способ сначала сделать один запрос и сохранить все это в двумерный массив?

Comment: извлечение результатов происходит за счет `mysql_fetch_array`.... делаете любой душе угодный цикл, в котором извлекаете значения в массив....

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то то же самое можно сделать и с while таким образом:

```
$c = 0;
$multiply = [];
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $multiply[$c] = $row;
    $c++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Для mysqli

В виде массива возвращает функция `fetch_all()`
В виде массива из ассоциативных массивов - `fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`

Полный пример кода (взят [отсюда](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/prepared_select))

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM multiplys WHERE sale = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $data_sale['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$multiply = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

## Для PDO

В виде массива возвращает метод `fetchAll()` 
В виде массива из ассоциативных массивов либо `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` либо заранее задать метод по умолчанию при коннекте

Полный пример кода (взят [отсюда](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/select))

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM multiplys WHERE sale = ?");
$stmt->execute([$data_sale['id']]); 
$multiply = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Так же PDO может возвращать данные в самых разнообразных форматах: массив вида ключ - значение, массив, индексированны не по порядку, а значением поля, трехмерный массив, группирующий записи по значению того или иного поля. См сооветствующие константы `PDO::FETCH_`